# Laravel Insert Data with Two Has Many Relationships using Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've tried it for like 10 times but still not able to do it. So here's what I wanna do.

I'm trying to **insert a Quiz which is having multiple Questions and each Question is having Multiple Options**.

**Quiz** -- *Has Many* --> **Questions** -- *Has Many* --> **Options**

For Example:

```
This is a Quiz?
    Question 1?
        Option 1
        Option 2
    Question 2?
        Option 1
        Option 2
```

I'm having 3 tables to store `Quiz Questions and Answers`. All of them are linked properly and I'm able to fetch and display Quizzes without any problem.

But I wanna insert a quiz. I know how to insert data with single has many relationship but have absolutely no clue how to insert data with 2 or more has many relations.

```
$quiz = new Quiz;
...
$quiz->save();
$questions = [new Question, new Question, ...];
$quiz->questions()->saveMany($questions);
```

I'm able to insert quiz and multiple Questions associated with that quiz but now i also want to insert **multiple options for each Question** like `$options1, $options2` etc.

I'm a newbie in laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have something like this

```
class Quiz extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = "you table name here";

    public function questions() {
        return $this->hasMany("Question", "question_id", "id");
        //where Question is your model for questions table
    }

}

class Question extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = "you table name here";

}

$quiz = new Quiz;

//set quiz data here
// $quiz->name = "name";

$quiz->save();


for ($i = 0; $i < count($questions); $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = new Question;
    $arr[$i]->quize_id = $quiz->id;;
    // Set other data here
}

$quiz->questions()->saveMany($arr);
```

Comment: I was able to insert multiple questions but i also want to insert multiple answers for each question too. So basically Quiz has many question and each question as many options. I'm not sure about the option part rest is fine.